# The return type of an async method must be void

Tags: asp.net, blazor, maui-blazor

I am currently following a course on how to build a ASP.NET blazor app and have reached a dead end. As the title states, the method CreateMauiApp() requires a void return type. One critical difference is that I am following a course that is 1 year old and does not cover Maui which I am using. Is there any work-around to this issue that anyone knows of?

```
 public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static async MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .RegisterBlazorMauiWebView()
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });
        //builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserManager, UserManager>();
        //builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserManager, UserManagerFake>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();

        builder.Services.AddBlazorWebView();


        var host = builder.Build();
        var currentUserService = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ICurrentUserService>();
        TestData.CreateTestUser();
        currentUserService.CurrentUser = TestData.TestUser;

        await host.RunAsync();
        
    }
}
```

}

Error messages:

Error   CS0161  'MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp()': not all code paths return a value    UdemyCourseIntro (net6.0-android), UdemyCourseIntro (net6.0-ios), UdemyCourseIntro (net6.0-maccatalyst), UdemyCourseIntro (net6.0-windows10.0.19041)    C:\Users\matej\source\repos\UdemyCourseIntro\UdemyCourseIntro\MauiProgram.cs    11  Active

Error   CS1983  The return type of an async method must be void, Task, Task, a task-like type, IAsyncEnumerable, or IAsyncEnumerator   UdemyCourseIntro (net6.0-android), UdemyCourseIntro (net6.0-ios), UdemyCourseIntro (net6.0-maccatalyst), UdemyCourseIntro (net6.0-windows10.0.19041)    C:\Users\matej\source\repos\UdemyCourseIntro\UdemyCourseIntro\MauiProgram.cs    11  Active

Comment: This is invalid C# for starters (on SO, always post full error messages).

Comment: @HenkHolterman Could you elaborate please? I have added the full error messages for you now.

Comment: My advice is don't try to learn a language using an old tutorial with preview frameworks. You clearly need to learn the basics of C#, before you learn about async/await (from your code sample) *before you jump into trying to work with Maui.* Also, you should practice reading error messages in full - your title shows you stopped reading part way through the error message. Read it again - search the internet for the error code. These are all basic skills that you need before you jump into the deep end of preview frameworks.

Comment: @MisterMagoo This isn't my code, it is the code that was provided by the course I'm currently doing. (https://www.udemy.com/course/aspnet-core-blazor/learn/lecture/22311232#overview) I have tried searching for the error codes and came up with nothing. My best guess is that there are no solutions to my specific issue because Maui is relatively new. I'm just looking for a work-around so I can continue the course.

Comment: You said "I am following a course that is 1 year old and does not cover Maui which I am using" - I advise not doing that.

Comment: @MisterMagoo Yes I understand that, but there are no courses currently on Maui. This is the closest thing to it. What do you recommend I start with to learn Maui?

Comment: Step 1 would be to learn C# - learn.microsoft.com is a good start.

Comment: Then if you really are sure you want to jump into Maui - start by creating a Maui/Blazor application from the latest template - and you will see how it is built correctly.

Comment: @MisterMagoo The course I am currently doing requires a basic knowledge of C# which I believe I have. But obviously my knowledge is not extensive enough for me to figure out how to implement something from a non-Maui project into a Maui project. I don't think studying C# specifically will give me any solutions to this issue. I have asked my senior developer in the company I'm interning at and he also has no solution to this issue. I understand this might be a tough one and I'm coming from a place of ignorance, but I genuinely just need a workaround for this.

Comment: Never spoke Maui before. I know Blazor though. I don't think the `CreateMauiApp` should be defined as async. Try to remove it.  I believe the `CreateMauiApp` should return a `MauiApp` object. that's what your code displays. So you must end the `CreateMauiApp` method with something like this:  `return builder.Build();`

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was exactly as someone politely stated in one of the comments. All I had to do is delete the async and return a MauiApp object.

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .RegisterBlazorMauiWebView()
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });
        //builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserManager, UserManager>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserManager, UserManagerFake>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();

        builder.Services.AddBlazorWebView();

        //builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

        var host = builder.Build();
        var currentUserService = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ICurrentUserService>();
        TestData.CreateTestUser();
        currentUserService.CurrentUser = TestData.TestUser;

        host.RunAsync();

        return host;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It doesn't make sense for a CreateApp() method to also run that App. This may work but it's still wrong.